# Not able execute protractor scripts due to this error "Cannot set property 'wrapCompare' of undefined"

Tags: protractor

When I am executing test scripts using protractor, It throws the below error. `Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'wrapCompare' of undefined`

> Node Version: 6.4.1 Protractor Version: 5.4.2 Browser(s):
>   Chrome74.0.3729.108 Operating System and Version Windows

**Conf.js:**

```
exports.config = {

  //seleniumServerJar: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  //directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName':'chrome',
    'shardTestFiles': true,
    'maxInstances': 1,
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  //comment for suite
  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 5000000
  }
};
```

**Spec.js**

```
describe('Enter GURU99 Name', function() {
  it('should add a Name as GURU99', function() {
  browser.driver.get('https://angularjs.org/');
  browser.sleep(20000);
  browser.element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('GURU99');
  var guru= driver.findElement(by.xpath('html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1'));
  expect(guru.getText()).toEqual('Hello GURU99!');
  });
 });
```

Traceback:

```
15:54:08] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'wrapCompare' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:258:43)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\jasmine.js:66:3)
    at q.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:405:43)
```

Comment: Try upgrade your nodejs to 8.x and re-install protractor 5.4.2, then rerun without using `await/async`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
describe('Enter GURU99 Name', function() {
  it('should add a Name as GURU99', async() => {
  await browser.get('https://angularjs.org/');
  await browser.waitForAngularEabled(true);
  await browser.sleep(20000);
  await element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('GURU99');
  const guru=element(by.xpath('html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1'));
  expect(await guru.getText()).toEqual('Hello GURU99!');
  });
 });
```

It will good if you refer basic example test before writing your test

Refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects for examples

Comment: Hi Madhan thanks for your answer, I have tried with your code but browser instance is opened and closed immediately. followed by the below error.

[17:41:32] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'wrapCompare' of undefined.

Comment: In order to use async/await you need Node 8.0 or greater (and Jasmine should be 2.7 or greater) https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await

Comment: Do mark the answer as correct if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i have figured out the solution. Actually the problem is with the installation. i have reinstalled the packages again. now it works fine.

1. Uninstall node.js
2. delete node related folders
3. install node.js
4. install protractor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I installed protractor again as global configuration

```
sudo npm install -g protractor
```

It's worked for